MacOS Shortcut using Shell Script exit status
If I use a "Run Shell Script" action, and then drag an "If" beneath it... it seems it's only able to interact with "Shell Script Result", which I think is any terminal output.
This means the If block can only switch on whether there's output or not.
Is there a way I can switch on exit status?  I'd like to pop up a notification on success, or a warning message on failure.

Are you trying to capture the output of the shell script as a text to be stored in variable? (Or instead gathering the numerical exit status which the shell assigns to $? )

The reason for the limitation is that "Shell Script Result" defaults to type "File". If you choose type "Number" instead and add echo $? at the end of your script, you can do a numeric comparison (equal, greater than, etc). $? is a variable set by the shell that stores the exit status of the most recently executed command, as mentioned in bmike's comment.

Have you given any thought to using logical AND and logical OR? The basic syntax would look like this -> print foo && print success || print failure.
